# Is 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' on non-OPTIONS responses a vulnerability?

Tags: http

In my application, I have noticed the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in GET and POST responses. All OPTIONS responses appear to correctly apply a good header value, but the rest do not.

I have removed the header, but was there any security implications with them existing beforehand?

Comment: It depends on the content served with this header. Basically, static, non-personalized, non-authentication-related content is not harmful.

Comment: Imagine the data is sensitive. How could it have be exploited?